# android emulator ip address

Tags: android

We are developing chat application and we want to fetch the IP address of the emulator which is connected to private network using the code.We are developing code in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
ipString = String.format( 
    "%d.%d.%d.%d", 
    (ip & 0xff), 
    (ip >> 8 & 0xff),
    (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
    (ip >> 24 & 0xff)
);
```

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351929/android-how-to-find-dynamic-ip-from-device). Don't forget to have INTERNET permission in your AndroidManifest!

Hope this helps!

Comment: We tried this.But we are getting 10.0.2.15.This is not the one we set in the emulator.We have set 192.168.xx.xx.Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this requires ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission.

Answer (score 2):

Try out this code -

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
try {
    for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
        NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
        for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
            InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
            if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
            }
        }
    }
} catch (SocketException ex) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
}
return null;
}
```

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720346/how-to-get-the-android-emulators-ip-address)

Comment: We tried this.But we are getting 10.0.2.15.This is not the one we set in the emulator.We have set 192.168.xx.xx.Please help.Thanks in advance